# How to extract the link on zomato?

Tags: python, css, scrapy, web-crawler, href

Trying to find only restaurant page links (such as https://www.zomato.com/istanbul/m%C3%BCkellef-karak%C3%B6y-istanbul ) from below start_url, Yet i am getting not only restaurant page links, all the links.

```
import scrapy

class ZomatoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zomato'
    allowed_domains = ["zomato.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.zomato.com/tr/istanbul/restoranlar?page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_css = response.css('.col-s-12')
        all_product = all_css.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        print(all_product)
        yield
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the scrapy documentation. It has a tutorial project for learning purposes.
To answer your question, this will get you all the restaurant links.

```
all_product = response.css('#orig-search-list .result-title::attr(href)').extract()

yield{
    'all_product': all_product
}
```